write swaras in telugu
I am looking to write notes involving some vedic literature in telugu. This involves swaras, like those mentioned by some of the users in their posts. I would like to know the following details in this regard.

How can these be added to the script? Do all fonts support these?
The script in some of the fonts does not look compact and neat. Do you have any specific recommendations about this?
Can these be supported in Latex?


I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs in a language stackexchange and not in the religion stack exchange

@Vijay Sharma Thank you for your comment. Since this is the site of stack exchange that many people are using to write scripts with these signs, I felt that the members of this site might be having better knowledge in this regard. I would be thankful if someone could suggest the right site where I can find an answer.
